# Javascript write time in specific format

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, datejs

I'm using Javascript along with Date.js and need to translate string representations of times.

I'm starting with times in this format:

```
3:00am
2:30pm 
11:00am
```

...and need to put them in this format:

```
03:00:00
14:00:00
11:00:00
```

I was thinking of starting with Date.parse() and then printing out the hours, minutes, and seconds.  But was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this such as something along the lines of `Date.format("HH:MM:SS")`

What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit::::**

It looks like you can use the format specifiers with Date.js: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

```
Date.parse("3:00am").toString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Oh you got it to work with parse!  Nice one.  I could only do it with parseExact.  You answered your own question.

Comment: I had issues with downloading the wrong version of Date.js.  You have to download it through this specific area thats not on the main site to get the most updated version: http://datejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/date-en-US.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer the OP is looking for. :-)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Show US Times in 24h form with Date.js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>  
    <script>
      var d = Date.parseExact("2:30pm", "h:mmtt");
      document.write(d.toString("HH:mm:ss"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Info on format specifiers here: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Answer (score 3):

[The answer to all your questions](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();

document.write(curr_hour + ":" + curr_min + ":" + curr_sec);

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Does this return the hours and minutes always using characters? ("02" instead of "2")

Comment: This does not use Date.js, nor does it parse the original string, nor does it pad out single-digit minutes and seconds.

Comment: But it gives a clear view on how to do it. From here, it's pretty easy to go on and add some functionality to add a leading zero when needed for example.. `if (curr_min < 10) { curr_min = '0' + curr_min; }` etc.

Comment: +1 for looking for the answer on your own before asking for help